# Как передать на принтер информацию о необходимости сшивать листы?

Tags: c#, принтер

Есть **Konica Minolta 554e**, на ней размножаем документы (всего 38 документов). Часть из документов печатается в две страницы на листе, часть одностраничные, некоторые из них скрепляются, некоторые нет (способ сшивания задается в параметрах принтера). Из этих документов собираются наборы в зависимости от внешних факторов (один набор может иметь 10 копий одного из документов и 12 копий другого, другой наоборот).

Все эти факторы уже вписаны в программу (на C#), и программа выдает страницу, по которой сотрудники собирают наборы из уже тиражированных экземпляров, **на сборку уходит 3-5 дней**. Разумнее было бы отправить на печать эти документы уже в нужном количестве и в нужном порядке, чтоб  печатать их уже комплектами, а не компоновать руками. И если двухсторонние документы я на принтер могу отправлять, то **как передавать информацию о необходимости их сшивать?**

Comment: Читай документацию на принтер, вот и все что можно ответить на такой вопрос. На самом деле вам нужно почитать ее, и посмотреть драйвера. на принтер, и исходя из этого посылать соответствующие флаги драйверам.

Comment: Может это поможет -> https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.printing?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 И вот -> https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.printing.printticket.stapling?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Printing_PrintTicket_Stapling И вот еще https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.printing.stapling?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Спасибо. Пока решил вопрос так: каждый документ распечатал в ps-файл (Pscript), с параметрами, которыми он должен идти на печать, в программе к каждому документу указал ps-файл. При помощи Socket отправляю файл на минолту. Всё это заняло 15 минут. Но нет контроля печати. Пока время есть буду изучать библиотеки, которые Sergey_73 порекомендовал.